# Lisp Interpreter

Tags: scripting

What is the cleanest way to build a lisp interpreter inside Mathematica.

I'm not looking for all the functions to be implemented but instead just the basic syntax.

Comment: Google (or get a couple of his books) papers by Gregory Chaitin re: Lisp. He did an implementation in *Mathematica* that's pretty cool...

Comment: [The Mathematica® Programmer](https://books.google.ch/books?id=tYriBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=mathematica+lisp+interpreter&source=bl&ots=kyidTcjuMy&sig=xIjf69rXRCgCBTQ9TNE19mGzdRQ&hl=de&sa=X&ei=bmYKVaauE4TEOPWQgdgN&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAjgU#v=onepage&q=mathematica%20lisp%20interpreter&f=false), [lisp.m: LISP interpreter](http://www.umcs.maine.edu/~chaitin/unknowable/lisp.m), [Appendix LISP interpreter in Mathematica](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~chaitin/lm.html)

Comment: Why did not you put this in an answer such that this question can be properly closed? No offense, I am trying to understand the not so always very clear policies of the site.

Comment: @ndroock1 of the 3 links none of them have working code that I could find.  If you find such code you are welcome to post it.  The 2 books cost money which prevents me from getting the appropriate code.  Working code is most often a requirement on this site which is probably why Louis didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: @ndroock1 On 2nd look this might work although I'm not sure how versioning will change the code https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~chaitin/lisp.m

Comment: I actually have a copy of the The Mathematica Programmer. All Maeder's books are considered classics I believe. Sadly he arguably does not describe a "real"  Lisp interpreter. But I get the